# Power and size of a statistical hypotheses testing

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I would like to know [here](http://31.42.184.140/main/1709000/3a5bc42f50a59a96a153e1995444b95c/Thomas%20Haslwanter%20-%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Statistics%20with%20Python%20%20With%20Applications%20in%20the%20Life%20Sciences-Springer%20%282016%29.pdf) on the page 132 why the pink (the power of the test) is **vertically aligned** with the blue (the Type I error). What is the intuition behind it ? Also, how the formula (7.2) in the snippet has arisen, what is $d$ there ?

[image]

Comment: The power of a hypothesis test is the probability of rejecting a false $H_0$. This probability is determined by integrating the true pdf that governs the distributed of observed data over the rejection region (which is the projection of the blue region onto the horizontal axis.)

Comment: @MatthewH. I have one specific problem with this. Must the projection in question be at the horizontal line **exactly** where the two p.d.f intersect (as the picture says) ? Or on the contrary it can be shifted on the right/left ?